# Entity Framework Join vs SQL View

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework

There are 2 tables in my database. (USERS and USERS_LANGUAGE) Which way should I join these tables ? Entity Framework or SQL View ? Which method is faster ?

Note : There are about 50 thousand records in the table

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The best way to remove doubts in choice EF or SQL is viewing EF generated code.

If it is similar to plain SQL you were going to write in your on view you will have no penalty difference. You will just tune proper indices. Also EF created indices on FK relationships automatically if you use Code First Model. But the problem is EF sometimes creates very strange queries and sometimes it is tricky to force EF generated mormal query.